# No operator "[ ]" matches these operands C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
const DayOfYearSet::DayOfYear DayOfYearSet::operator[](int index){

        if(index < 0){
            
            cout << "Error! Index cannot be negative.." << endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        if(index >= _size){

            cout << "Error! Index overflows the array size.." << endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        return _sets[index];
    }

    const DayOfYearSet DayOfYearSet::operator+(const DayOfYearSet &other){

        vector <DayOfYear> temp;
        for(auto i = 0; i < other.size(); ++i){
            temp.push_back(other[i]);
            .
            .
            .


        }
    }
```

Hey, I have an issue in the `temp.push_back(other[i])` line of the code which the compiler says no operator "[]" matches these operands. As you can see I overloaded the index operator as member function but its not working? What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance..

EDIT: _sets is `DayOfYear* _sets` as a private data member of the class `DayOfYearSet`.

Comment: `DayYearOfSeat::operator[]` is not a `const` member function. In `DayOfYearSet::operator+`, `other` is a `const DayOfYearSet`, so you cannot call `other[i]` on it. For comparison see how [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) has `const` and non-`const` versions of `operator[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use `operator[]` on `const DayOfYearSet &other`, but that function is defined to only work on objects that are **not** `const`.

You should correctly const-qualify this function.

```
const DayOfYearSet::DayOfYear DayOfYearSet::operator[](int index) const
//                     This function can be used on const objects ^^^^^
```